# Is there any way to create a dynamic disk via code on windows?

Tags: c++, windows, powershell

We can use "convert dynamic" command in diskpart utility to change a disk to be dynamic on windows 2012.
It there any way we can do it via code?
I've checked the [Storage Management powershell cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh848705(v=wps.630).aspx),  and [Storage Management API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh830612(v=vs.85).aspx). But none of them provide the capability.

Comment: It doesn't look like it's possible with Powershell since the functionality is deprecated.

Comment: Hi Micky, can you show me where can I find the statement of the deprecation? And it's not restricted to powershell. Other programming language is fine.

Comment: Here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/tip_of_the_day/archive/2014/04/25/tip-of-the-day-dynamic-disks-and-windows-powershell.aspx

Comment: You realize you can launch diskpart as a subprocess to perform the task for you?  (Obviously it would be cleaner to use an API, but I'm not sure there is one.)

Comment: Mickey, I didn't realize that. Actually, I'm trying to create a spanned volume with code. Which requires the disk to be dynamic. The point is does Robert mean the dynamic disk feature is deprecated or the code for manipulating dynamic disk is deprecated. I don't think MS is gonna deprecated dynamic disk as a whole.

Comment: Harry, thanks. I know I can do it this way. But, as you said, it's not clean enough. I'd rather to use api if possible.

Comment: Dynamic disks are a legacy technology.  Their use is no longer recommended.

Answer (score 1):

You can create dynamic disk via VDS. Get `IVdsSwProvider`, then create `IVdsPack`, call `IVdsPack->AddDisk` for each of the target disks, and finally call `IVdsPack->CreateVolume`.

Comment: According to the documentation, AddDisk is for raw disks only: "You cannot use AddDisk to redefine the partitioning on an existing disk."  Looks like the MigrateDisks method is the way to go if you want to convert an existing volume.  (I'm not sure which scenario the OP was dealing with, but probably best to mention both.)

Answer (score 0):

i have tried this before you can actually do it using command line;

Open a command prompt and type diskpart.
At the DISKPART prompt, type list disk. Make note of the disk number you want to convert to dynamic.
At the DISKPART prompt, type select disk .
At the DISKPART prompt, type convert dynamic.

But be careful with disks that contain multiple installations of windows.
Also try 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731274.aspx#BKMK_CMD
Goodluck...

Comment: Thanks. I understand we can do it with diskpart. Want to know if this can be done with code.

Comment: Sure... if you are familiar with visual studio you can create code that will link to a command line.. you can as well create an interactive app in visual studio, user selects disk number, disk type etc... then do the diskpart  is it simmilat to what you want?

Comment: I'll use it if there is no other way around.